# PowerShell Install MSI with Property File

Tags: powershell

I looking to replace our old command files with PowerShell file to install msi on a number of servers with a view of automating installations remotely.

What I am trying to do, and this is how can you get PowerShell to install an msi where the installation relies on a details coming from a property file as one argument along with logging out the installation as a log file and setting a new user name and password?

Currently our old cmd file looks a bit like this:

msiexec /I mymsi.msu /quiet /lv mymsi.log USERNAME=AName PASSWORD=APassword CONFIG="C:\Some.properties.env"

What I want to do is recreate this but in PowerShell, but I have not been able to find an example that works.

Comment: At the end of the day is Powershell just a command line interface just like cmd. If this command line worked before it should work with Powershell as well. Where did you search for that you couldn't find something helpfull?

Comment: @Olaf Quoting rules are tricky due to it going through two parsers

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `Start-Process` and `Splatting` to make it readable and functional:

```
$startProcessParams = @{
    'FilePath'         = "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\MSIEXEC.exe"
    'ArgumentList'     = @(
        '/i', 'mymsi.msu'
        '/quiet'
        '/lv', 'mymsi.log'
        'USERNAME=AName', 'PASSWORD=APassword', 'CONFIG="C:\Some.properties.env"'
    )
    'WorkingDirectory' = $PSScriptRoot
    'Wait'             = $true
    'PassThru'         = $true
}
$process = Start-Process @startProcessParams

return $process.ExitCode
```

Be sure to set `WorkingDirectory` to where your `.msu` file is living.

---

### [`about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

### [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Use `'/i'` (_Latin Small Letter I_)  instead if `'/l'` (_Latin Small Letter L_) for _Install and configure a product_ as per `msiexec /?`. BTW, why do you use a delimiter comma / _newLine_ inconsistent way?

Comment: @JosefZ I thought something was off. This is the reason for code blocks!